# Check if File exists and update the table column

Tags: c#, ssis

I have a table [dbo].[Missing_MyFastor] which has the information as below.

```
sdukey                            srcDocPath                           docName            IsExists
44276482    \\172.17.22.159\images33\h_drive\2003\lrg03\    LRG03-FA35880406_280A-1P.TIF    0
44276483    \\172.17.22.159\images33\h_drive\2003\lrg03\    LRG03-FA35880429_280A-1P.TIF    0
44276484    \\172.17.22.159\images33\h_drive\2003\lrg03\    LRG03-FA35896269_280A-1P.TIF    0
44276485    \\172.17.22.159\images33\h_drive\2003\lrg03\    LRG03-FA35896271_280A-1P.TIF    0
44276486    \\172.17.22.159\images33\h_drive\2003\lrg03\    LRG03-FA35896276_280A-1P.TIF    0
```

I have to write C# script to check if file exists and update the IsExists=1 if exists. Else ignore.
while updating the where clause should be on sdukey. I should iterate on each row. I need help in fetching sdukey and file path from the DataTable at each iteration level.

Mycode:

```
#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
#endregion

namespace ST_241de8cb1bbf41e9bfbfa9800831fe10
{
public void Main()
        {
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server=AZABCD001;Database=TRDDataMart;Trusted_Connection=True;");
            SqlCommand count = new SqlCommand("select count(1) from [dbo].[Missing_MyFastor]", con);
            SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand("with cte(Id,Folder_FileName) as (select  row_number() Over(order by sdukey asc) RN,CAST(srcDocPath AS VARCHAR)+docName as DN from  [dbo].[Missing_MyFastor]) select top 10 * from cte",con);
            con.Open();
            count.CommandTimeout = 0;
            int x = (int)count.ExecuteScalar();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query);
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dataTable);

            foreach(DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dataTable.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(row[j].ToString() + " ");

                    string filepath = row[j].ToString();

                    if(File.Exists(filepath))
                    {   
                        string q= "update [dbo].[Missing_MyFastor] set IsExists=1 WHERE sdukey="+ row[j].ToString();
                        SqlCommand update = new SqlCommand(q, con);

                        update.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }

            }
            //int i = 0;
            //while(i<=x)
            //{

            //}            

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: I am unable to fetch filepath,sdukey  from DataTable for each loop iteration. I read that column should be mentioned while fetching from array of row. Need help in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning the `sdukey` in your select query so change the select query to include it like below:

```
with cte(Id, sdukey, Folder_FileName) as (select  row_number() Over(order by sdukey asc) RN, sdukey, CAST(srcDocPath AS VARCHAR(1000))+ docName as DN from  [dbo].[Missing_MyFastor]) select top 10 * from cte
```

Once you have the resultset having the `sdukey` you can utilize that in the update query and in the `foreach`:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
  {
    string path = row["Folder_FileName"].ToString();              
    if (File.Exists(path))
      {
         string sduKey = row["sdukey"].ToString();
         string q = "update [dbo].[Missing_MyFastor] set IsExists=1 WHERE sdukey=" + sduKey.ToString();
         SqlCommand update = new SqlCommand(q, con);

         update.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
   }
```

**On side note:**

In the select query you are using the `cte` just to assign the unique id to each row, other than that I dont see any use of it. You can check if you can directly return the table data from the query something like below-

```
select sdukey, CAST(srcDocPath AS VARCHAR(1000))+ docName as Folder_FileName from  [dbo].[Missing_MyFastor]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are now checking if a file exists in the path of the value of each column (of course neither of the files `"44276482"`, `"\\172.17.22.159\images33\h_drive\2003\lrg03\"`, `"LRG03-FA35880406_280A-1P.TIF"`, or `"0"` exists).

You need to extract the path and the file name column values from the row, combine them to a full file path and then check if the file at the full file path exists:

```
foreach (var row in dataTable.Rows)
{
    string path = row["srcDocPath"].ToString();
    string fileName = row["docName"].ToString();
    string filePath = Path.Combine(path, fileName);
    if (File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        string sduKey = row["sdukey"].ToString();
        // Now you have the sduKey of the row with an existing file.
        // Preferably store the keys in a list and update them all at once 
        // with a single command, instead of doing it separately in every iteration.
    }
}
```

Comment: The combining is happening the select query!